# Push item onto array on condition in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want something like this and I would like to know if this is possible in JavaScript in one line, or I have to write an if statement

```
// these versions adds fasle to the array if condition = false
let arr = await getArray(params).push(condition && itemToAdd);
arr = await getArray(params).push((() => condition && itemToAdd)());

// this version adds undefined to the array if condition = false
arr = await getArray(params).push((() => { if (condition) return itemToAdd })());
```

(the reason I included the getArray part is cuz that's how it looks in my code and I don't actually save this array to a var `arr` only its being returned right away to its calling function, so that's why I don't want to add a line for the if statement...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do it in a single line, but this can work

```js
let arr = [...await getArray(), itemToAdd].slice(0, condition ? undefined : -1);
```

Here we are pushing the `itemToAdd` in the array regardless of the condition, but we remove the last element (`itemToAdd`) if the condition is false.

Comment: yup this is what I'm looking for, thx a million!

Comment: need it in one line for clean code (I'm sort of crazy about clean code...)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with reactjs then you can use useState for conditions

```
const [isCondition, setisCondition] = useState(false);
```

//but you need if/else to change useState

```
if(this_happens) {
```

setisCondition(true)
} else {
setisCondition(false)
}

//you can do it as like

```
let arr = await getArray(params).push(isCondition && itemToAdd);
```

Comment: this is in a backend NodeJs env, and I have no clue what you answered here (not well formatted) and your solution doesn't solve my problem cuz the push function will still push false onto the array if the state = false...)

Comment: what I want is the push function not to push anything onto the array if some condition is false, which while I'm typing this comment I'm realizing is not possible...